# Zend framework 2 how use validator chains in fieldsets

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-validate, zend-inputfilter

I need to use validator chains in the getInputFilterSpecification method of the fieldset to use the breakChainOnFailure parameter and get only one error message.

I know make validator chains using InputFilter classes how explain the [zend documentation](https://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/modules/zend.input-filter.intro.html), e.g.

```
    $input = new Input('foo');
    $input->getFilterChain()
          ->attachByName('stringtrim', true)  //here there is a breakChainOnFailure
          ->attachByName('alpha');
```

But I want make the same using the factory format.
Where can I put the breakChainOnFailure parameter in this sample:

```
    $factory = new Factory();
    $inputFilter = $factory->createInputFilter(array(
        'password' => array(
            'name'       => 'password',
            'required'   => true,
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'not_empty',
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'string_length',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ));
```

Answer (score 9):

To answer your question we need to look at the InputFilter Factory, there we find the [`populateValidators` method](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/InputFilter/Factory.php#L285-316). As you can see, for validators it's looking for a `break_chain_on_failure` key in the spec. You just need to add that to your validator spec array...

```
$factory = new Factory();
$inputFilter = $factory->createInputFilter(array(
    'password' => array(
        'name'       => 'password',
        'required'   => true,
        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'not_empty',
                'break_chain_on_failure' => true,
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'string_length',
            ),
        ),
    ),
));
```

By the way, the `attachByName` method signatures for `FilterChain` ([here](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Filter/FilterChain.php#L168)) and `ValidatorChain` ([here](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Validator/ValidatorChain.php#L147)) are not the same. In your first example you're calling the method on a filter chain, which doesn't support break on failure at all. (you might also note that it's the third parameter of the validator chain method and not the second)

Comment: Thanks very much for you help. You are right, my attachByName method example was modified to do the example. I thought were the same case.

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing my code, I would need to use the break_chain_on_failure parameter in a validation chain specification using instances of validator classes (not factory specifications).

view example:

```
    'password' = array(
        'required' => true,
        'validators' => array(
            new NotEmpty(),  //these are validator instace classes
            new HostName(),  //and them may be declared before
        ),
    );
```